# Check string is null or empty in linq

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have string with empty space("**________**")

```
string MyNote= Convert.ToString(Session["MyNote"]);

if(MyNote!=null || MyNote != "")
{


}
```

MyNote != "" does not work if string has more space so

How can I check my string is "" or null  by using linq in C#?

Comment: If you really wanted to use LINQ the correct answer would have been `if (MyNote != null && MyNote.Any(c => !char.IsWhitespace(c))) ...`. But I doubt this is about LINQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) is the method you're looking for.

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

Alternatively, using your idea:

```
if(MyNote!=null && MyNote.Trim() != "")
{

}
```

or

```
if(MyNote!=null && MyNote.Trim().Length == 0)
{

}
```

Comment: You should change `||` into `&&`. You actually check for Is **Not** Null Or **Not** WhiteSpace. This will even throw an exception if MyNote is null.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(MyNote!=null || MyNote.Length > 0) //or you may want to set different value than 0
{


}
```

Comment: And with trimming it won't work either since it throws an exception when MyNote is null.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 string MyNote = Session["MyNote"] == null ? String.Empty : Session["MyNote"].ToString();
```